# htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am working on a project and it utilizes a shortened url for redirection, I've gotten the following code to work perfectly:

```
XBitHack      Off
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9A-Za-z]{4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*) ./getdeck.php?deck=%1 [L]
```

Now I want to add a second redirect rule for /a/([0-9A-Za-z]{4} but no matter how I write it, the new rule fails. Can anyone help explain what I'm missing?

Examples I have tried:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*) ./deck/makedeck.php?deck=%1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/([0-9A-Za-z]{4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*) ./deck/makedeck.php?deck=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to repeat the first two conditions.